# How to recover a deleted text file that is still open in vim?

Tags: vim, data-recovery, rm, undo

I have text file that is still open in vim, but the original text file has been accidentally deleted. How can I recover it? The text file is still open in vim, so its original data is still stored in the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data in the original file still appears in vim just save the file and close vim and the data that was in the original file will be saved. If you close the file without saving it the changes won't be written to the disk, and if you already saved changes that you made to the original file in vim the contents of the original file will be changed/lost when you close vim. According to your reply to my comment:

> I saved file then closed vim, and the file was not lost.

so I reposted my original comment as this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on another file, if I save the file, it will be again write on disk.

Comment: If you close the file without saving it the changes won't be written to the disk, but if you already saved it tin vim the original file will be lost when you close vim. Did you already save the file in vim or not?

Comment: @karel I saved file then closed vim, the file was not lost.